# YUI DATA TABLE PKG.dataTable.render(); TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getId'

Tags: yui

Hi i am using YUI data table

initially i am loading table with no records(empty), i am taking the input from user and making an AJAX call which is returning JSon object, when i try to

```
PKG.dataTable.showTableMessage("Loading...");
        var recorSet= PKG.dataTable.getRecordSet();
        var records=recorSet.getRecords();
        records.push(data);
        recorSet.setRecord(records);
                   PKG.dataTable.render();
```

when i try to add rows i am getting following exception

```
     PKG.dataTable.render();
   TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getId'
```

please help me out thank you in advance

Comment: It looks like you might have forgotten to put the css id into `PKG.dataTable.render('#cssId')`